# Threejs Decal not showing

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to create a decal on my mesh using three.js and react-three-fiber. I believe I correctly set up the mesh and material but for some reason the decal is not showing up on the canvas.

[image]

This is the parent component that holds both the model, backplate, and decal.

```
<Canvas camera={{ position: [0, 0, 2], fov: 70 }}>
    <Lights />
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <Model flipped={flipped} returnMesh={setMesh} />
        <Decal mesh={mesh} />
        <Back />
    </Suspense>
</Canvas>
```

This is part of the component where I create the t-shirt mesh from a .glb file. The mesh is passed back to the parent and then to the Decal component.

```
let geometry, material, mesh;

// GEOMETRY
geometry = useGLTF("/tshirt.glb").nodes.tshirt.geometry;

useEffect(() => {
    material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: "orange" });
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
}, []);
```

This is how I am trying to set up the decal mesh:

```
extend({ DecalGeometry });

const Decal = ({ mesh }) => {
    let decalGeometry;

    useEffect(() => {
        if (mesh) {
            decalGeometry = new DecalGeometry(
                mesh,
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
                new THREE.Euler(0, 0, -1, "XYZ"),
                new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
            );
        }
    }, [mesh]);

    return (
        <mesh geometry={decalGeometry}>
            <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="red" />
        </mesh>
    );
};
```

I am getting no errors, the decal just doesn't appear. I hope someone has some insight. There isn't a lot about Decal Geometry with threejs out there, even less specific to r3f.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This is another question of mine but even though they concern the same project, they don't have much in common otherwise.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I have no answer to either of the questions, yet. As far as I understand, they are quite different. One is about a mesh not showing up, the other is about the rotation matrix of a mesh not being updated.

Comment: do you have a github repo by any chance ? thanks !

Comment: Hi @KevinGilbert, I don't have a minimal reproduction of this right now since the issue is rather old. However, feel free to poke around the repo with the working code: https://github.com/maxibenner/teeshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `decalGeometry` before it is assigned. This is because callbacks given to `useEffect` are executed *after* `Decal` is called.

Suggested fix: use the `useMemo` hook.

e.g.

```js
extend({ DecalGeometry });

const Decal = ({ mesh }) => {
    const decalGeometry = useMemo(() => {
        return new DecalGeometry(
            mesh,
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new THREE.Euler(0, 0, -1, "XYZ"),
            new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        );
    }, [mesh]);

    return (
        <mesh geometry={decalGeometry}>
            <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color="red" />
        </mesh>
    );
};
```